# confused about std dev

Tags: r, standard-deviation

[image]I'm working on a project that involves some statistics: I need to obtain the standard deviation from a set of numbers.
I've obtained two different results from the following:

1. Calculating sample std dev manually using the formula, or calculating it in Excel using the STDEV function - obtained the same result with both
2. Plotting the numbers into a Shewhart individual/moving range control chart in R, using library(qcc) - obtained a different value for std dev compared to the above.

Does anyone know why these might be different?

Thank you!

[image: excel calculation]

Comment: Possibly https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=n-1+standard+deviation explains it--but I can only guess, because you don't provide adequate information.  Could you show small examples of each result?

Comment: The answer presumably lies in whatever qcc does as using var() in R agrees with Excel.

Comment: Control charts may use a different estimator of $\sigma.$ The sample standard deviation is considerably biased as an estimator of normal population SD σ, for small sample sizes. In control charts. SD is sometimes estimated in terms of sample ranges. // Some OR books have tables with the appropriate constants to convert ranges to SDs for sample sizes up to $n=15$ or $20$ (assuming normal data).

Answer (score 1):

Comment continued: Consider normal samples with $n=5.$
Divide sample range by 2.326 for unbiased estimate of $\sigma.$

```
set.seed(2021)
rge = replicate(10^6, diff(range(rnorm(5))))
mean(rge)
[1] 2.325985
```

So divide sample range by 2.326 for estimate of $\sigma=1.$

```
set.seed(2021)
rge.adj = replicate(10^6, diff(range(rnorm(5)))/2.326)
mean(rge.adj)
[1] 0.9999936   # very nearly 1
```

Sample standard deviations tend to underestimate population $\sigma,$ especially for small $n.$

```
set.seed(2021)
s = replicate(10^6, sd(rnorm(5)))
mean(s)
[1] 0.9401148   # downward bias
```

---

For $n=6$ (different seeds)

```
set.seed(2021)
rge = replicate(10^6, diff(range(rnorm(6))))
div = mean(rge);  div
[1] 2.534639

set.seed(213)
rge.adj = replicate(10^6, diff(range(rnorm(6)))/div)
mean(rge.adj)
[1] 0.9994023   # pop SD well estimated by adjusted range

set.seed(1234)
s = replicate(10^6, sd(rnorm(6)))
mean(s)
[1] 0.9517331   # pop SD underestimated by sample SD
```

Furthermore, the adjusted range has a noticeably smaller root mean square error for $n$ as small as $6:$

```
sqrt(mean(s - 1)^2)     # RMSE of sample SD
[1] 0.03471834
sqrt(mean(rge.adj-1)^2) # RMSE of adjusted range
[1] 0.0007772492        # smaller
```